# Error on Flash builder 4

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder

Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant. Date is found on one of my components but other components that utilized date didn't have this error. How come? Is this a flash builder 4 bug?

Comment: Code sample would help. You're likely just missing an import directive somewhere

Comment: You should always assume that missing imports or build path errors are **never** IDE bugs, unless you are using very unstable beta versions.

Comment: @weltraumpirat: since the IDE is derived from Eclipse, it's a safe bet to declare it guilty until proven innocent. And then jail it anyway, just to be sure.

Comment: @Lohoris: Do I smell a whiff of tool bias?

Comment: @weltraumpirat: just a whiff.